# getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE) freezes the 5.0 emulator

Tags: android, android-nsd

Trying to execute the following line

```
NsdManager Mgr = (NsdManager)Ctxt.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
```

in the Android 5.0 emulator (ARMv7a, on Win64) freezes the emulator. The debugger never reaches the next line, the emulator doesn't respond to buttons, can be only closed.

Tried from both a background thread and from the main one. The context is an Activity.

Permissions in the manifest include:

- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE

The same line works as expected on a 4.4 emulator and on a 4.1 device. Any ideas what's different on 5.0 and/or what's wrong with the line, please? Did anybody try this on a 5.0 device?

EDIT: same on Intel emulator.

Comment: It gets stuck after running a few times successfully on a KitKat emulator. I have to reboot the emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSD in Android is all kinds of broken. Don't even try to make it work, go back to JmDNS.

These are the damning bug reports:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35585
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39750

Also, [Nsd Manager Android Crashing on 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458323/nsd-manager-android-crashing-on-4-2-2)

Comment: Do you know if it is better now?

Comment: Even if they've fixed it, existing 5.0 is still broken.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It looks like an OS issue, not a SDK issue.  Am I right?  Even though I am targeting a specific device, I may still want to avoid it.